# asterisk tree looping in c++

Tags: c++, for-loop

How do i flip the output around so its smallest to largest?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (){
    int m, n;
    for (m=0; m<10; m++) {
        for (n=0; n<m; n++) cout << " ";
        for (n=0; n<(19-2*m); n++) cout << "*";
        for (n=0; n<m; n++) cout << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change initialization, conditions and decrement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just flip it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (){
    int m, n;
    for (m=9; m>=0; m--) {
        for (n=0; n<m; n++) cout << " ";
        for (n=0; n<(19-2*m); n++) cout << "*";
        for (n=0; n<m; n++) cout << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```